# Spin camera around origin/focus in Unity editor

Tags: unity, editors

I have used Blender a bit, and like the way the camera in the editor orbits around the focus/origin when dragging with middle click.

I've recently been using Unity a little and *despise* the camera controls; right-dragging sort of moves the camera's view a little and middle-dragging moves the camera along a plane. Not very good to get to different angles I'd like to see from.

**Is there a way to set the Unity 3D editor's camera to work like Blender's?**

Comment: Did you try [orbiting the camera with alt-drag](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SceneViewNavigation.html)?

Comment: @DMGregory thank you!!! That worked exactly like I wanted and I had no idea it existed lol

Comment: In future, if you have a question about how to use an application's interface, the manufacturer's documentation about that interface is often a very useful starting point.